# How can I make Sphinx show an inheritance diagram in HTML build?

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx, graphviz

I am using Sphinx to produce a class diagram from a py module. I have used the inheritance-diagram directive in the RST file for the module I wish to diagram, per Sphinx documentation. However, the build produces only the Graphviz markup, rather than an actual plot. I have included both inheritance_diagram and Graphviz in my Sphinx config file. Is there another directive I need in order to get a graphical output? Thank you.

Comment: It seems like you have done what is needed. But without more details it is hard to say what the problem is. Does Sphinx emit any warnings or error messages?

Comment: @mzjn No error messages. Just Garphviz script in the HTML files where a plot should be. Btw, the script looks as though it correctly describes the inheritance tree. Is there perhaps another tool i need to include in the config file?

Comment: post your config file please, let us take a look at this. thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that Graphviz is installed?

Comment: @mzjn Wow, now I feel pretty dumb. I did not realize that was a separate install. I figured it was included in Sphinx or WinPy.

Answer (score 0):

For those coming in from your favorite search engine looking for something to copy and paste, here are some details.

- Make sure [Graphviz](http://graphviz.org) is installed.
- In your Shinx `conf.py`, include `'sphinx.ext.graphviz'` in your extensions. I also recommend placing this in your `conf.py` for resolution-independent output (no one wants a fuzzy PNG):

  `graphviz_output_format = 'svg'`
- Add a line like this where you want an inheritance diagram (taken from the docs):

  ```
  .. inheritance-diagram:: sphinx.ext.inheritance_diagram.InheritanceDiagram
  ```

  If you just want the name of each class without the path:

  ```
  .. inheritance-diagram:: sphinx.ext.inheritance_diagram.InheritanceDiagram
     :top-classes: sphinx.util.docutils.SphinxDirective
     :parts: 1
  ```

  Of course, replace the classes/paths above with your own.

The [full docs are here](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/inheritance.html).